# How to filter dataframe being displayed in plotly time series graph

Tags: filter, plotly, plotly-python

I am trying to filter a plotly express timeline graph by a categorical column.

I would like something similar to how the legend works with the customers in this example, but also have an option to select and filter the different 'Resource' types.

Any help is much appreciated.

Here is an example of what I currently have.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd


data = {'Product': ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I'], 
        'Customer':['John','John','Cindy','Maria','Cindy','Maria','Jose','Jose','Cindy'], 
        'Start':['1/1/2023','2/1/2023','3/1/2023','1/15/2023','2/5/2023','4/1/2023','5/1/2023','6/1/2023','7/1/2023'], 
        'End':['2/1/2023','3/1/2023','4/1/2023','2/20/2023','5/3/2023','5/1/2023','6/1/2023','7/1/2023','8/1/2023'], 
        'Task':['DV','DV','DV','DV','DV','DV','DV','DV','DV'], 
        'Resource':['PEP','PEP','PEP','LFC','LFC','LFC','PEP','LFC','PEP']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig = px.timeline(df, title="Example", x_start='Start', x_end='End', y='Product', color='Customer')

fig.update_xaxes(
    rangeselector=dict(
        buttons=list([
            dict(count=7, label='1w', step='day', stepmode='backward'),
            dict(count=1, label='1m', step='month', stepmode='backward'),
            dict(count=90, label='90d', step='day', stepmode='backward'),
            dict(count=1, label='1y', step='year', stepmode='backward'),
        ])
    )
)

fig.update_layout(autosize=True, 
                  xaxis_title='Date', 
                  yaxis_title='Product',
                  template='plotly_dark',
                  xaxis_rangeselector_font_color='black',
                  xaxis_rangeselector_activecolor='rgb(63,192,218)',
                  xaxis_rangeselector_bgcolor='white')

fig.show()
```